# I am getting exception in this program?

Tags: java

I am getting an exception in this program. I have tried to do some changes but its still not working. I am trying to write data from demo.txt to demo1.txt but its giving a `NullPointerException`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.io.*;

class CopyFile{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String str = null ;

        try {
        File f = new File("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo.txt");
        if(f.exists())
        {
            if(f.canRead())
            {
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
                BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
                DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bin);

                while((str=din.readLine())!=null)
                    System.out.println(str);
                    writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
                    din.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public static void writeTextFile(String fileName, String s) {
        FileWriter output;
        try {
            output = new FileWriter("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
            writer.write(s);
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
>
> at CopyFile.writeTextFile(CopyFile.java:37)
>
> at CopyFile.main(CopyFile.java:21)

Comment: The exception should also give you the line number where it is thrown, which should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: And can you mark the line visually in the code sample? Really helps us out if you say, "I'm getting exception and it's happening on the following line." Would also be helpful if you posted the actual exception output.

Comment: NullPointerException occurs when there is null pointer and it tells the line number.

Comment: @assylias The post contains the stacktrace..., at the very end of this post

Comment: Fault happens at `writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
` per stack trace.

Comment: @user2229178 I am wondering why you need `fileName` as an argument, but don't use it in your `FileWriter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't underestimate the use of curly braces with loops. Here's your code:

```
while((str=din.readLine())!=null)
    System.out.println(str);
    writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
    din.close();
```

Here, only `System.out.println(str)` will be running in a loop, and the next line will be executed after the loop exits, and obviously str here will be `null`. So when you pass `null` to the `BufferedWriter's` `write()` method - you get a `NullPointerException`. Fix your code to be:

```
while((str=din.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(str);
        writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
}
din.close();
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing braces around the body of your `while` loop.

Therefore, Java parses it like this:

```
while((str=din.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
din.close();
```

Thus, the `writeTextFile()` line only runs after the `while` loop *finishes* – when `str` is `null`.

---

The moral is **Always indent your code correctly**.
Use your IDE to automatically format your code, and this kind of problem will be much more obvious.

Alternatively, switch to a whitespace-sensitive langauge such as Python.

Comment: Changed it still same Exception.

Comment: What did you change it to?

Comment: Changing this will close `DataInputStream din` in each loop!

Comment: @Joetjah: Yes; he needs to change it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File fdir = new File("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src");
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File(fdir,"demo1.txt"));
file.write(new Scanner(new File(fdir,"demo.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next());
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to avoid more trouble later:

You pass the `fileName` to thr `writeTextFile`-methode, but never use it.
So instead of doing:

`new FileWrite("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt");`

You sould do:

`new FileWriter(fileName);`

The original question has already been answered by Egor.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for so quick response. Its is working now :)

Comment: You should mark at least one of these answers as the actual answer to your question, so that this one gets "closed".

Answer (score 0):

It may be going wrong here:

```
while((str=din.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(str);
    writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
    din.close();
}
```

You close `din` in each loop. Perhaps it should be outside of the loop.

It may be going wrong here:

```
while((str=din.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(str);
    writeTextFile("/home/newlabuser/workspace/CopyFileDemo/src/demo1.txt",str);
}
din.close();
```